# What is SystemType.Database in LobSystem?

Tags: 2010, external-content-type

I am trying to create external content type programmatically with SharePoint 2010. Here is the [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff464321(v=office.14).aspx) which I am using for reference.

I have created a console application and put the same code as provided. But I am facing issue in below line:

```
// Make a new Contact LobSystem
            // NOTE: Assume that the "AdventureWorks" LobSystem 
            // does not already exist.
            LobSystem adventureWorksLobSystem = 
                contactModel.OwnedReferencedLobSystems.Create(
                "AdventureWorks", true, SystemType.Database);
```

I am not able to pass value of `SystemType.Database`. I am not able to find what could be the use of it as well as how can I pass that value. Can anyone tell me what should be the value and how to pass it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add reference of `Microsoft.BusinessData.dll`. Then add namespace `Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel`. This will enable you to use access SystemType enum.You can use different values of this enum like `SystemType.DataBase,SystemType.WebService,SystemType.Custom,SystemType.Wcf,SystemType.DotNetAssembly`.Please refere [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.businessdata.metadatamodel.systemtype.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for more details.Hope this will work for you.